# how to call a function I created in VBA in onther function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I created a function in VBA and I want to call it in onther function I created in VBA. what is the correct syntax to do this?

this is the function i want to call:

```
Function AlreadySigned()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
j = ActiveCell.Row - 1
Dim tmp As String
tmp = ActiveCell.Value
For i = 3 To j
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = tmp Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

in this function:

```
Function AlreadyRegisterLoop()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To j
    Cells(i, 2).AlreadySigned()
Next i
End Function
```

but there is an `eror: syntax eror` in the 6th line.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The reason why I ask is because I don't think you need to call a function inside a function in this case... I have a feeling that you may not know (no offence meant) what a `Procedure` and a `Function` does.. So do let us know what exactly are you trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but that is not the way to call a function.

From what I understood, I think the below would work for you.

You should pass a `Range` object and use that Range object in the Function instead of `Activecell`

```
Function AlreadySigned(rn As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
j = rn.row - 1
Dim tmp As String
tmp = rn.Value
For i = 3 To j
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = tmp Then
        rn.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i
End Function


Function AlreadyRegisterLoop()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For i = 3 To j
    Call AlreadySigned(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2))
Next i
End Function
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: ther is still an eror: "Type mismatch"

Comment: Type mismatch @Mikku

Comment: @NoaBenNathan .. I have changed the Sheet reference to Active sheet. Try now.

Comment: The dreaded unnecessary `Call`? Why not use idiomatic VBA: `AlreadySigned ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)` instead of some anachronistic throwback to the days of `GoSub`?